# Allow only access to a specific mod_rewrite generated URL, deny all other http requests

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a REST API being served at by apache2 at www.mysite.com.

the rest api is accessible at www.mysite.com/rest/...

However there is no folder named /rest on the box, its all happening by rewrite rules.

How can achieve the following using the .htaccess file:

1) allow access to All requests coming to www.mysite.com/rest/... (i.e. any request, as long as it is sub to the virtual folder /rest)

2) allow any other request ONLY from a specific IP address e.g. fictitious IP 123.45.67.89; for all other IP addresses, deny

Reason for this is I do not want anyone even as much as landing on the admin page which is at www.mysite.com.

Thank you

Content of httpd.conf is as follows:

```
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/htdocs/web">
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
AllowOverride None

<IfVersion < 2.3 >
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from All
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
 Require all granted
</IfVersion>
                   <IfModule pagespeed_module>
                   ModPagespeedDisallow "*"
                   </IfModule>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#   Force login to be SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.cloud\.myapp\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?web/login/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/web/login/$1 [R,L]

# if ack directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L]
### END: .htaccess inline ###

<LimitExcept GET HEAD PUT DELETE PATCH POST>
    Allow from all
</LimitExcept>

<IfDefine USE_PHP_FPM>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteOptions Inherit

   RewriteRule ^(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://uds=%2fopt%2fbitnami%2fphp%2fvar%2frun%2fmyapp.sock/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [P,L]
</IfDefine>
```

Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/htaccess.conf"

Comment: Post your current htaccess rules.

Comment: I've done so as an edit of original post.

Comment: @PanamaJack: I've now added some directives which correctly detect if the IP is not 123.45.67.89 but it is wrongly denying access to everything including anything under /rest/...

I have RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !rest/   ....then....
RewriteRule ^(.+) /tmp/$1 [L]

What little tweak do I need?

Answer (score 1):

Try and replace this

```
<IfVersion < 2.3 >
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from All
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
 Require all granted
</IfVersion>
```

With this below and see how it works.

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 123.456.67.89
```

replace the `123.456.67.89` IP address with your IP address

Then add another directory directive under the other one for the /rest folder.

```
<Directory /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/htdocs/web/rest>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from All
</Directory>
```

How that works. Likewise you can also do it in htaccess in root and /rest.

Comment: this has the effect of giving a 403 forbidden message to all, including the anointed IP address. This is happening to all requests, /rest inclusive. Please recall there is no physical folder with ../rest so will the directory directive really work in .conf? Also how do I translate these to htaccess rewrite directives if that's the cause.